A movie about a female con artist
I watched this movie between 1998 - 2001. It's about a female con artist or femme fatale because she's sexy and smart: 

The film starts with a sex scene. The male asks her about his performance, and she tells him that he can find his money on the desk.
She wears a formal suit and leaves to work where she gets in a conflict with her boss and says something like "if I had balls (if I was a man) you wouldn't treat me like that' and leaves the company. 

She starts to work from home via internet (something like stock market). 
There is a scene where she is having sex and her Asian agent starts a cam call and she gets out of bed to talk to him topless, then he's like "wow" and then she covers herself with bed sheets.
She seduces a son of a rich man (who owns a glass factory or something) and he gives her a present, a glass vase or something but it breaks and she cries over it in white underwear. She seduces him into a sexual relationship and they have quickies in his father's office. 
Then she hires a black street cup game-magician with good sight to steal his credit information, while he is using a computer at a public net cafe or something, she also steals his money and discovers that he is conspiring to kill her, so she fakes her death in a house burn (apparently he burns her house).
The final scene she is sitting and watching the house burns. 
Unfortunately I don't know any names of the actors!

Welcome to Movies & TV! We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

I think this is Spider's Web Starring Billy Baldwin and Kari Wuhrer.  The plot points you mention align pretty well with the plot description on IMDB.  Also, the Plot Keywords on IMDB, match many of your details including "shell game" (you called it cup game), web camera, money transfer, etc.
The only slight variation I can find is this movie was released in 2002 - just 1 year past your range.

YOU ARE GENIUS. Thank you so much.

My wife would tell you that is a stretch, but good descriptions make for more fruitful searches.
